# Collectors.toMap write a merge function on a different attribute of object than the one which is not used as value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to create `Map<String, String>` from `List<Person>` using Stream API.

```
persons.stream()
       .collect(Collectors
            .toMap(Person::getNationality, Person::getName, (name1, name2) -> name1)
```

But in the above case, I want to resolve conflict in name attribute by using Person's age. is there any way to pass merge function something around the lines `(age1, age2) -> // if age1  is greater than age2 return name1, else return name2` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To select a person based on its age, you need the `Person` instance to query the age. You cannot reconstitute the information after you mapped the `Person` to a plain name `String`.

So you have to collect the persons first, to be able to select the oldest, followed by mapping them to their names:

```
persons.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getNationality, Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge)),
        o -> o.get().getName())));
```

Comment: Started right with the official resource, the [package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description), [the class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), [lambda tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), [stream tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html), [related enhancements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/lambda_api_jdk8.html) and Stackoverflow, of course.

Answer (score 5):

order the elements of stream by age and then just choose first:

```
persons.stream()
       .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge).reversed())
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getNationality, Person::getName, (n1, n2) -> n1));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a helper data structure, it is possible if you first keep your Person info and perform the merge based on it and apply the mapping afterwards:

```
public void test() {
    final List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    final BinaryOperator<Person> mergeFunction =
        (lhs, rhs) -> lhs.getAge() > rhs.getAge() ? lhs : rhs;

    final Function<Person, String> mapFunction = Person::getName;

    final Map<String, String> personNamesByNation =
        persons.stream()
            .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getNation, // KeyMapper Person.getNation: Map<String, List<Person>>
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.reducing(mergeFunction), // Merge Persons into single value via merge function: Map<String, Optional<Person>>
                            Optional::get), // unwrap value: Map<String, Person>
                        mapFunction))); // apply map function afterwards: Map<String, String>
}
```

Comment: You can also use `final BinaryOperator<Person> mergeFunction = BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge));`, which is what you get when using `Collectors.maxBy(…)` instead of `Collectors.reducing(…)`, so these solutions are equivalent.

Comment: Hm, true, when I started your answer wasn't there yet. I guess my answer also works if you want to aggregate Persons into a new Person object, but for the question of the OP yours looks cleaner.

Comment: Indeed, it was overlapping. Nothing wrong with that. I just wanted to mention the equivalence, in case, any reader is wondering whether there are functional differences.